# command substitution - cat file inserts quotes

Tags: bash, quoting, command-substitution

In bash, given these files:

```
$ cat noquotes.txt
s/a/b/g
$ cat quotes.txt
"s/a/b/g"
```

Why does

```
$ echo "aaa" | sed -e $(cat noquotes.txt)
bbb
```

succeed, but

```
$ echo "aaa" | sed -e $(cat quotes.txt)
sed: 1: ""s/a/b/g"
": invalid command code "
```

fails?

If if run `set -x` first, then I see that

```
$ echo "aaa" | sed -e $(cat noquotes.txt)
+ echo aaa
++ cat noquotes.txt
+ sed -e s/a/b/g
bbb
```

and

```
$ echo "aaa" | sed -e $(cat quotes.txt)
+ echo aaa
++ cat quotes.txt
+ sed -e '"s/a/b/g"'
sed: 1: ""s/a/b/g"
": invalid command code "
```

So it seems like there are extra quotes being inserted around the contents of `noquotes.txt`, but not around `quotes.txt`.

Comment: @don_crissti let me add another input file, `spaces.txt` with content `-e "s/a /b/g"`. Now when I try `echo "a a" | sed $(cat spaces.txt)` I get a similar error. Would `spaces.txt` be better written as `-e s/a /b/g`? This seems contrary to the command-line usage of sed where I need to add quotes around the sed command like this: `echo "a a" | sed -e "s/a /b/g"`

Comment: @don_crissti thanks that's helpful. One more example that would help clarify: I can run `echo "a b " | sed -e "s/a /b/g" -e "s/b /c/g"` => `bc`. What should the contents of `multi.txt` be if I want to write `echo "a b " | sed "$(cat multi.txt)"` and similarly produce output `bc`?

Comment: @don_crissti Interesting, I didn't know about `;` in `sed`. You're right, this is an XY question. In reality I want to pass multiple `-x module` arguments to the `browserify` command, where each module is specified in a newline-separated file, and each `module` is contained in double-quotes within the file. The `modules` may be file paths

Comment: @don_crissti I'll give it a shot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37016419/pass-multiple-externals-to-browserify-command-line-from-file . In general I'm interested in learning about bash, so I wanted to inquire about a general-purpose way of passing command line arguments from a file into a bash command using command substitution. I chose `sed` as an example hoping it would be familiar to the unix.stackexchange community

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with that `browserify` thingie... It looks like you're trying to build up a command line based on the contents of some files so Etan's suggestion there isn't bad though I'm not sure why you have posted the question there - stackoverflow is a black hole - questions are forgotten in the next 3 minutes. Wait a couple of days and if you don't get any reply delete it from there and re-post it here on Unix&Linux (don't cross-post as it will be closed).

Answer (score 3):

There is a step in the processing of the command line that is called the *quote removal* step.  This is usually the last thing that happens before the command is executed and it removes the outer sets of quotes that you used to quote strings in the command.

For a command such as

```
sed -e "s/a/b/g"
```

this step make sure that the `sed` command is given the string `s/a/b/g` as its last argument, and *not* `"s/a/b/g"`.

When you are reading the string `"s/a/b/g"` from a file using `cat` in a command substitution, the quotes will not be removed, as they are not part of the original command (they are part of the data read from a file).

This means that `sed` will receive the literal string `"s/a/b/g"` as the expression to run, and it therefore complains that it does not understand the initial `"` (it was expecting a `sed` command).

As for the output from `set -x` tracing, treat it as nothing more than debugging output. The `bash` shell will add quotes around strings that contain certain characters in the trace, so it's not indicative of what the quoting of any single argument *actually* was or how it was interpreted by the invoked utility.

---

As an aside, to run `sed` with an editing script on file, use the `-f` option:

```
sed -f noquotes.txt <<<"aaa"
```

Also, the `y` command in `sed` could be used to transliterate between one set of single characters to another more efficiently than a substitution with `s` would.  Your `s/a/b/g` substitution is better written as `y/a/b/`.

If this is the *only* operation that you need to perform, then it may be even more efficient to use the simpler `tr` utility:

```
tr a b <<<"aaa"
```

Answer (score 2):

> So it seems like there are extra quotes being inserted around the contents of noquotes.txt, but not around quotes.txt.

This is just Bash being helpful. You'll notice it will put quotes around things whenever there's a symbol that would otherwise be interpreted by Bash. It acts just like you would, using quotes only when necessary. Try to put any of the following into quotes.txt:

```
s/a$/a/g
s/"hi"/"bye"/g
```

The list goes on and on.

Now back to your original question. First of all, your `sed` prints out a weird message. From `set -x` it's obvious that the input is `"s/a/b/g"`, not `""s/a/b/g"`. I wouldn't trust this message. Here's what GNU sed 4.2.1 prints out for `"s/a/b/g"`:

```
$ sed -e '"s/a/b/g"'
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `"'
```

Pretty clear: since the first char is a command name and there's no command named `"`, `sed` has no idea what to do.

Comment: It's just a matter of formatting the error message. Just like for non-gnu users  `unknown command: \`"'` may also be a weird message that they wouldn't trust: a backtick followed by a double-quote and single quote ?

Comment: At least with GNU the quotes are balanced. Here, there's a quote at the beginning but not at the end.