# Bash: Legitimate folder paths not recognized

Tags: bash, find

I tried using `sed` to convert `PATH` paths as an input to `find`:

```
User.Name@Machine-Name ~
$ echo $PATH | sed -e 's/:/\n/g' \
  | sed -n -e 's=.*="&"=' -e '2,5p'

   "/bin"
   "/usr/local/bin"
   "/usr/bin"
   "/c/Program Files/Eclipse Adoptium/jdk-8.0.392.8-hotspot/bin"
```

The paths are quoted to protect spaces.  Unfortunately, they aren't recognized properly when submitted to `find`:

```
User.Name@Machine-Name ~
$ find \
   $(echo $PATH | sed -e 's/:/\n/g' | sed -n -e 's=.*="&"=' -e '2,5p') \
   -iname '*libc*'

   find: ‘"/bin"’: No such file or directory
   find: ‘"/usr/local/bin"’: No such file or directory
   find: ‘"/usr/bin"’: No such file or directory
   find: ‘"/c/Program’: No such file or directory
   find: ‘Files/Eclipse’: No such file or directory
   find: ‘Adoptium/jdk-8.0.392.8-hotspot/bin"’: No such file or directory
```

In fact, the spaces aren't protected and are interpretted as argument delimiters.

On the other hand, if I simply type in a quoted path, it works fine:

```
User.Name@Machine-Name ~
$ find "/bin" -iname '*libc*' # Finds nothing, but no syntax error
User.Name@Machine-Name ~
```

How can I understand this and how can I efficiently convert `PATH` paths into arguments (say, for `find`)?

Comment: "How can I understand this?" – https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/280892/108618

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski: Thanks.  Very educational.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to preserve empty elements in the `PATH`, then you could try

```
IFS=: read -ra patharray <<<"$PATH"
```

and then (noting that bash arrays are zero indexed)

```
find "${patharray[@]:1:4}" -iname '*libc*'
```

Comment: I have a comprehension question: why do you restrict the array to the first four elements with `${patharray[@]:1:4}`?

Comment: @Cyrus I was attempting to implement the OP's `sed -n -e '2,5p'`

Comment: Thank you, steeldriver and Cyrus.  I found [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335815) helpful for the dicing `patharray`.  Such a helpfully readable variable name!